# PHP_NORMAL_READ cutting off the data being sent

Tags: php, sockets

I need some help please,I have problem in reading the binary data that was sent by the device via socket.I could not receive the exact data that was sent. I am using this code

```
$data = @socket_read($read_sock,2048,PHP_NORMAL_READ);
```

I am using PHP_NORMAL_READ because it will stop reading with this "\r\n".

but when I receive,the data is not exact it only receive few binary data.

Comment: Remove this `@`! Then set `error_reporing(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and tell us, what does it shows.

Answer (score 2):

The length parameter specifies the **maximum** length that will be read from the stream. The PHP documentation is a bit misguiding on this subject, but what I think it means is, that you will get:

- less than or exactly 'length' bytes
- at least one byte
- no '\r' or '\n' in the response, unless it is the only character

Most of the Socket APIs you encounter work this way, they may give you less bytes than requested, because more bytes may not be available and the data may arrive in smaller parts than that the device sent them in. The solution is to read from the socket repeatedly, until you get what you want (that means until you get string ending with newline, in  your case).

You also may want to consult http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-read.php, where the commenters suggest the functions is somewhat buggy when used with PHP_NORMAL_READ. It might be worth searching for some socket library for PHP that supports readLine.